Why are these typ. values greater than min. values in the datasheet of ADC128s102?
I'm reading the table of AC electrical characteristics (page 7) in the datasheet of ADC128s102 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc128s102.pdf. However, I noticed that the minimum value of some parameters is even greater than the typical values. For example, the minimum fs sample rate is 500ksps. But its typical value is 50ksps.
Can anyone explain why it is the case? And please point it out if I misunderstood the datasheet. Thank you!

Are min and typ swapped in your title?

It looks odd initially. It's also not discussed in the description.
Bear in mind that this is a charge redistribution ADC, it works by holding charge on capacitors. As such, it will have a minimum frequency, below which too much charge leaks from the capacitors during a clock cycle to meet the accuracy specification.
The guaranteed minimum frequency it will work down to is 500 kS/s.
Typically though, the charge leakage is low enough that it will still work down to 50 kS/s.
Nowhere in the data sheet does it recommend working at this low frequency. Indeed, to save power, they suggest sleeping between conversions performed at 500 kS/s. However, the large margin between guaranteed and typical low frequencies should give the user a nice fuzzy warm feeling that's it's working well at 500 kS/s rather than struggling.


Why are these typical values greater than minimum values

Because the limit is imposed by the leakage in the capacitors inside the device. So, you're guaranteed performance with a short period, but typically can go slower than that.
The specs look like:



Value
Symbol
Min
Typ
Max




Maximum sampling period
TS(max)

20μs
2μs


Minimum sampling frequency
fS(min)=1 / Ts(max)
500kHz
50kHz




When the spec itself is a maximum, the typical value has to be larger than the maximum maximum value. You can reach a higher maximum most of the time, but can't bet on it. Correspondingly, when the value is  a minimum, the typical value has to be lower than the minimum minimum value.
The part is guaranteed to have leakage low enough only to support a maximum sampling period of 2μs. But typically it is good enough that the maximum sampling period can be longer.

Sometimes "min" and "max" are unclear as to whether they are specifying the range of stimuli that will yield desired operation, or the minimum, or the range of ways the part might behave.  Saying something like "Sample period part can tolerate without loss of accuracy: 2us minimum 20us typical" would make the meaning of "typical" much clearer; wording for "frequency" would be more awkward; perhaps simply "frequency corresponding to above sample period".
